# Real Analysis proof (unique positive square root)

Tags: analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a >0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}, \exists$  unique $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x>0$ such that $x^{n} =a$.

I've done the case for n=2 and a=2 but not too sure on generalisation.

Suppose $ \exists, x,y >0 \in \mathbb{R}$ st $x^{n}=y^{n}=a \Rightarrow (x^{\frac{n}{2}}-y^{\frac{n}{2}})(x^{\frac{n}{2}}+y^{\frac{n}{2}}))=0$. Then $x=y$ hence unique.

Let $$A=\{x>0:x^{n}\leq a\}$$

Let $x \in A$. Then $x >a$ and $x^{n} \leq a$. If $x \leq \frac{a}{n} \Rightarrow x \leq a$. If not then $\frac{a}{n} < x \Rightarrow x \leq x^{n} \leq a$. Hence $A$ is bounded above.

By LUB axiom $A$ has an LUB say $\alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \alpha >0$. Let $\epsilon > 0, \exists x \in A$ st $0< \alpha - \epsilon < x \leq \alpha$.

Then $\alpha^{n}-n\alpha\epsilon+... < x^{n} \leq a, \forall \epsilon >0$. Hence $\alpha^{n} \leq a$.

Suppose $\alpha^{n} <a$ consider $\epsilon>0.$ Then $(\alpha+\epsilon)^{n}=\alpha^{n}+...+\epsilon^{n}$. Choose $\epsilon$ st $n\alpha\epsilon+...+\epsilon^{n} < a-\alpha^{n} \Rightarrow (\alpha+\epsilon)^{n} < \alpha^{n} + a - \alpha^{n} < a \Rightarrow \alpha+\epsilon \in A$. Contradiction as $\alpha$ is an LUB. Hence $\alpha^{n}=a$

Comment: Hint: show that $f(x)=x^n$ is continuous and strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+\,$.

Comment: We have to do it using this approach unfortunately :(

Comment: Does LUB mean least upper bound?

Comment: @Numbertheorylearner Then you should edit the question and add that mention.

Comment: @dxiv Continuity approach elegant but unnecessary.  See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy given by the OP (i.e. original poster) is good, and simply needs some formality in choosing $~\epsilon.~$  For ease of use, I will use the variable $~v~$ in place of $~\epsilon.~$

While the assertion is normally proven via the intermediate value theorem, which depends on the continuity of $~f(x) = x^n,~$ a much more primitive method is available that is based on the LUB (i.e. least upper bound) axiom.  This primitive method does not require that $~f(x)~$ be recognized as a continuous function.

In "Calculus 2nd Ed." 1966, Vol. 1, page 29 (section I3.13), Tom Apostol uses the Least Upper Bound axiom to prove that the equation

$$y^2 = x ~: ~x \in \Bbb{R^+}$$

has exactly two solutions, one positive and one negative.  Then, in section I3.14, Apostol asserts (without proof) that $~\forall ~n \in \Bbb{Z^+} ~: ~n ~$ odd, and $~\forall ~x \in \Bbb{R},~$ there exists a unique $~y~$ such that $~y^n = x.$  Apostol further remarks that a proof that depends on the Least Upper Bound axiom is viable.

My proof is a generalization of the approach taken by Apostol in his section I3.13.

---

Without loss of generality, $~x \neq 0,~$ since $~y = 0~$ is the unique solution to $~y^n = 0.~$

$\underline{\text{I Claim that the assertion is true for all} ~x > 0, \text{and for all} ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}.}$

That is, I claim that $~\forall ~x > 0, ~\forall ~n \in \
\Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}}, ~\exists ~\text{unique} 
~\textbf{positive} ~y ~\text{such that} ~y^n = x.$

Assume that the claim is true, and consider the equation $~y^n = x,~$ where $~x < 0.~$

For all $~y,~$ let $~z = -y.~$ 
Since $~n~$ is assumed to be odd, you have that $~y^n = x \iff z^n = (-x),~$ which is positive.  Further, as a consequence of the claim, the equation $~z^n = (-x)~$ has a unique positive solution.  Also, since $~n~$ is assumed odd, the equation $~z^n = (-x)~$ can not have any negative solutions.  Therefore, the equation $~y^n = x,~$ must also have a unique solution, and this solution will have $~y < 0.$

So, the problem reduces to proving the claim.

---

$\underline{\text{Proof of Claim}}$

Here, it is assumed that $~x > 0.$

Let $~S~$ denote the set given by $~\{ ~s \in \Bbb{R} ~: ~s^n \leq x ~\}.$

One of Apostol's preliminary results is that
$~a < b, ~0 < c \implies ac < bc.$ 
As a consequence of this, noting that $~c > 0 \iff (1/c) > 0,~$ you also have that $~ac < bc, ~c > 0 \implies a < b.$

By repeated application of this result, you have that $~\forall n \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~0 < a < b \implies 0 < a^n < b^n.$ 
For example, with $~n=2,~$ you have that $~a^2 < ab < b^2.~$

$$x^{n-1} < (1 + x)^{n-1} < (1 + x)^n \implies 
\frac{x^{n-1}}{(1 + x)^n} < 1 \implies \\
\frac{x^n}{(1 + x)^n} < x \implies \frac{x}{1 + x} \in S.$$

Further, by the binomial theorem, $~(1 + x)^n > nx > x.~$ 
Therefore, $~s \in S \implies s^n < x < (1 + x)^n \implies s < (1 + x).$

Therefore, $~S~$ is a non-empty set bounded above.  Therefore, there exists a unique value $~y~$ equal to the least upper bound of $~S.~$

Further, since $~\dfrac{x}{1 + x} > 0, ~y~$ must be positive.

So, the entire problem reduces to proving that both $~y^n < x,~$ and $~y^n > x,~$ both lead to contradictions.

That is, once it is proven that $~y^n = x,~$ where $~y~$ is the LUB of $~S,~$ this will prove that $~y~$ is the unique positive solution to $~y^n = x,~$ since:

- For all $~s~$ such that $0 < s < y,~$ you have that $~s \in S \implies s^n < x.$
- $~y_1 > y \implies (y_1)^n > y^n = x.$

As a preliminary step, let

$$W = \max\left[ ~ \binom{n}{1}y^{n-1}, ~\binom{n}{2}y^{n-2}, ~\cdots, ~\binom{n}{n-1}y^1, ~1 ~\right]. \tag1 $$

---

$\underline{\text{Assume that} ~y^n > x}$

Set $~\displaystyle v = \min\left[ ~\frac{1}{2}, 
~\frac{y^n - x}{nW}, \frac{y}{2} ~\right].$

This implies that $~0 < v < y,~$ and $~v \leq \dfrac{1}{2}.~$

Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}v^k < \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}v \\
\leq \sum_{k=1}^n W \times \frac{y^n - x}{nW} = y^n - x.$$

Set $~c = y - v \implies 0 < c < y.~$

It also implies that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}c^{n-k}v^{k} < \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}v^k < y^n - x.$$

Therefore,

$$y^n - c^n < y^n - x \implies x < c^n.$$

Therefore, $~\forall s \in S, s^n \leq x < c^n \implies s < c.~$

Therefore, $~c~$ is an upper bound for $~S.~$

Since $~c < y,~$ this contradicts the assumption that $~y~$ is the least upper bound for $~S.$

---

$\underline{\text{Assume that} ~y^n < x}$

Set $~\displaystyle v = \min\left[ ~\frac{1}{2}, 
~\frac{x - y^n}{nW} ~\right].$

This implies that $~0 < v \leq \dfrac{1}{2}.~$

Set $~c = y + v \implies c > y.$

Then

$$c^n - y^n = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}v^k < \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}y^{n-k}v \\
\leq \sum_{k=1}^n W \times \frac{x - y^n}{nW} = x - y^n.$$

This implies that $~c^n < x \implies c \in S.$

Since $~c > y,~$ this contradicts the assumption that $~y~$ is an upper bound to $~S.$