# $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^3=0$ - Epsilon-Delta definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

So, I just finished this proof, but I can't find any place where I can confirm if it's correctly done or not. There I start:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}x^3=0$

$ 0 \lt |x-0| < \delta$ $\implies$ $|x^3-0| \lt \varepsilon%$

I started with

$|x^3-0|$ $=$ |$x^3$| = $|x^2|$ $\cdot$|$x$| $\lt$ $|x^2|$ $\cdot$ $\delta$ $=$ $\varepsilon$ 
Then I set $\delta \lt 1$:

$|x| \lt 1$ 
Multiply everything by $|x|$

$|x^2| \lt$ $|x|$ 
But knowing that $|x^2|$ $\lt$ $|x|$, I get
$|x^2|$ $\lt$ $|x|$ $\lt$ $\delta$, I go back to the $\varepsilon$ inequality:
 
$|x^3-0|$ $=$ |$x^3$| = $|x^2|$ $\cdot$|$x$| $\lt$ $|x^2|$ $\cdot$ $\delta$ $\lt$ $\delta$ $\cdot$ $\delta$ $=$ $\delta^2$ $=$ $\varepsilon$, so $\delta$ $=$ $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$

Proof:

let $\delta$ $=$ min{$1$,$\sqrt{\varepsilon}$}
$|x| \lt 1$
$|x^2| \lt |x| \lt \delta$, so
 $|x^3|$ $=$ $|x^2|$ $\cdot$|$x$| $\lt$ $|x^2|$ $\cdot$ $\delta$ $\lt$ $\delta$ $\cdot$ $\delta$ $=$ $(\sqrt{\varepsilon})^2$ $=$ $\varepsilon$

Is this one a valid proof? Again, I really can't find this problem anywhere to get a feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Be careful about stating $|x| < 1 \implies |x^2| < |x|$, this is not in general true (take $x = 0$).

Comment: Is that possibility allowed in cases like this?

Comment: Yes, your proof looks good.  A moderately more standard approach is that when $~\delta \leq 1, ~$ you have that $~\delta^3 \leq \delta.~$  Therefore, it is sufficient for $~\delta~$ itself to be $~\leq \epsilon,~$ and $~\leq 1.~$  That is $~0 < |x| < \delta < 1 \implies 0 < |x^3| < \delta^3 \leq \delta \leq \epsilon.$

Comment: Your proof is ok, but you could take more naturally $\delta=\sqrt[3]\varepsilon$ (this is optimal, i.e. it is the largest allowable $\delta$).

Comment: @user2661923 That was a good one. Before posting, I was thinking about this way too! I don't think I'll even need to do that multiplication step.

Comment: Re my last comment, the underlying point is that often, with limit problems that involve $~x^n ~: ~n \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 2}},~$ a common artificial device is something like $~\delta \leq (1/10) \implies \delta^n \leq \dfrac{\delta}{10^{n-1}}. ~$  This allows you to construct a $~\delta :: \epsilon~$ relationship that is strictly linear.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! Gonna try this!

Comment: @AnneBauval Just did the proof this way, incredible how I didn't think about this, the proof would be a lot shorter too.

Comment: The problem with @Anne’s suggestion is that typically one needs to know that $f(x)=x^3$ is continuous to prove that every number has a cube root. So the choice of $\root3\of\epsilon$ is some circular reasoning.

Comment: @TedShifrin The most common (and most elegant) method used to prove (for example) unique positive (integer) roots of positive numbers is based on continuity.  However, a more primitive approach is feasible, based on nothing more than the least upper bound axiom.  See, for example [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137339/real-analysis-proof-unique-positive-square-root/4776690?r=SearchResults&s=8%7C24.9910#4776690).

Comment: @user2661923 Yes, I realize, but I want to discourage this approach to epsilonics.

Comment: @TedShifrin Okay, I'll play this game.  Alternative discouragement - You can assume, without loss of generality that $~\epsilon < 1,~$ since if the $~\delta::\epsilon~$ relationship/implication holds for $~\epsilon_1,~$ then it holds for all $~\epsilon > \epsilon_1.~$  Then, since $~\epsilon < 1,~$ you have (for example) that $~\sqrt[3]{\epsilon} > \epsilon.~$  Therefore, you can simply specify that the *expression in* $~\delta < \epsilon.~$ This will automatically imply that the *expression in* $~\delta < \sqrt[3]{\epsilon}.$